# CSS animations wont work in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-animations

I have inserted some CSS animations.  They work fine in FireFox but not Chrome.  Is there any way of fixing this?

Here is my code I have a background image which moves slow.  At the bottom there is an animation that moves faster.

```
body {
  background-image: url('images/bg.png');
  animation: animatedSky 40s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animatedSky {
    from { background-position: 100% 0; }
    to { background-position: 0 0; }
}

#bottom { 
   width: 100%; 
   height: 40px; 
   background-image: url('images/bottom.png');
   background-position: 0px 0px;
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
   animation: animatedBackground 8s linear infinite;
   position: absolute;
   margin-top: 600px;
   }

@keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { background-position: 100% 0; }
    to { background-position: 0 0; }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For keyframes in chrome and safari you need to use the webkit prefix:

`@-webkit-keyframes`